# How to write Swift Codable struct with Date property to Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp, codable

I'm fairly new to Firebase/Firestore and am currently writing an iOS/Swift app to both write/read a `Customer` struct to the DB.

The Customer has a `validTill` of type `Date`. At the moment, I can't seem to be able to write this particular field to Firestore because, I assume, it has to be written as a `Timestamp`.

But then how can I continue using `Codable` while still being able to encode the `Date` into a `Timestamp`? Using the `Codable` extension is really convenient because it allows me to to do `customer.dictionary` and everything is automatically encoded and ready to go, but then the `validTill` doesn't work.

Most questions/answers I so far came across are more about "decoding" Timestamp to Date which isn't an issue with the code I wrote. Just encoding is the problem.

Any ideas how to go about this?

```swift
extension Encodable {
  var dictionary: [String: Any]? {
    guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self) else { return nil }
    return (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)).flatMap { $0 as? [String: Any] }
  }
}


public struct Customer: Codable {  
  public var companyName :String?
  public var address     :Address
  public var contactName :String
  public var email       :String
  public var mobile      :String
  public var website     :String?
  public var validTill   :Date
    
  public init?(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        
    guard let address = Address.init(dictionary:(dictionary["address"] as? [String:Any])!),
          let contactName = dictionary["contactName"] as? String,
          let email = dictionary["email"] as? String,
          let mobile = dictionary["mobile"] as? String,
          let validTill = dictionary["validTill"] as? Timestamp else {
            return nil
          }
  
    self.address = address
    self.contactName = contactName
    self.email = email
    self.mobile = mobile
    self.companyName = dictionary["companyName"] as? String
    self.website = dictionary["website"] as? String
    self.validTill = validTill.dateValue()
  }
    
  public init?(companyName: String?, address: Address, contactName: String, email: String, mobile: String, website: String?, validTill: Date) {
    self.companyName = companyName
    self.address = address
    self.contactName = contactName
    self.email = email
    self.mobile = mobile
    self.website = website
    self.validTill = validTill
  }
}
```

Comment: Putting aside databases and native types for a moment, is the `validTill` field a day (2019-05-24), a local timestamp (2019-05-24T00:12:15-08:00) or a zulu timestamp (2019-05-24T00:00:00Z)?

Comment: @bsod yes, it is a day. so 25-05-2019 for example

Comment: If it’s just a day, store the days as strings in the database (“2019-05-20”), the server-side date objects won’t make things easier. Plus this keeps the data agnostic since all databases can store strings. Use the standard YYYY-MM-DD format so the strings can easily be converted into Swift date objects (if needed). This format also allows the strings to be sorted alphanumerically a-z which sorts them chronologically. Therefore, on the client, you just need to get today’s day-string (using a date formatter) and check if `validTill` is greater than or equal since the strings are in YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: Great, thanks. I guess I will go with using a String. Not the solution I was hoping for but it will do for now

Answer (score 1):

You can turn a `Date` into a `Timestamp` like so:

```swift
let timestanmp = Timestamp(date: Date())
```

See the reference documentation for details about [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Timestamp).